# Can I apply Huffman Coding again and again?

Tags: algorithm, huffman-code, greedy

I was wondering can I apply Huffman coding again and again ? 
For example,

```
File A --->  (Huffman) --->  File B (smaller size than A)
File B ----> (Huffman) --->  File C ?
```

Is it logically correct to apply Huffman again on `File B` output.?

Comment: It's unlikely to get smaller, and in most cases a re-encode will result in a larger output. For one thing, the encode uses codewords that are not on byte boundaries, so a re-encode would need to look for redundancies based on codeword sizes instead of byte boundaries.

Comment: Give it a try. The reason it doesn't work is the same for any compression algorithm. The more you compress, the closer the data comes to being perfectly random. And the more random the data is, the harder it is to compress. So after the first Huffman encoding, you'll find that the symbols are approximately equal in frequency, so the ideal Huffman code for the second pass is to leave the symbols unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can. It might not decrease the size of file, though. So you may try applying it as long as it is useful.